# import web based .txt file into python

Tags: python, data-import

I think this is simple but I am not finding an answer that works. The data importing seems to work but separating the "/" numbers doesnt code is below. thanks for the help.

```
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
url = "http://jse.amstat.org/v22n1/kopcso/BeefDemand.txt"
f = opener.open(url)
content = f.read()
# below are the 3 different ways I tried to separate the data
content.encode('string-escape').split("\\x")
content.split('\r')
content.split('\\')
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the variable "content" you are using?

Comment: The start of the web pull is below

Out[265]: b'Year\tChickPrice\tBeefPrice\tBeefConsump\tCPI\tDPI\tRealChickenPrice\tRealBeefPrice\tRealDPI\t\t(RDPI-Mean)^sq\n1965\t37.24500733\t59.5\t\t99.5\t\t31.5\t2505\t118.2381185\t\t188.8888889\t7952.380952\t63240362.81\n1966\t39.44150776\t62.2\t\t104.1\t\t32.4\t2675\t121.7330486\t\t191.9753086\t8256.17284\t68164389.96\n1967\t36.38550716\t60.7\t\t106.5\t\t33.4\t2828\t108.9386442\t\t181.7365269\t8467.065868\t71691204.42\n1968\t38.00900748\t63.5\t\t109.7\t\t34.8\t3037\t109.2212859\

Comment: The "content" is the data pulled from the web URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) for reading and analysing this kind of file. It supports reading directly from a url and also gives meaningful analysis ability.

```
import pandas
url = "http://jse.amstat.org/v22n1/kopcso/BeefDemand.txt"

df = pandas.read_table(url, sep="\t+", engine='python', index_col="Year")
```

Note that you have multiple repeated tabs as separators in that file, which is handled by the `sep="\t+"`. The repeats also means you have to use the python engine.

Now that the file is read into a dataframe, we can do easy plotting for instance:

```
df[['ChickPrice', 'BeefPrice']].plot()
```

[image: plot resut]

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `csv.reader` or `csv.DictReader` to parse the contents. Make sure to set the delimiter to tabs, in this case:

```
import requests
import csv
import re

url = "http://jse.amstat.org/v22n1/kopcso/BeefDemand.txt"

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

text = re.sub("\t{1,}", "\t", response.text)

reader = csv.DictReader(text.splitlines(), delimiter="\t")
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

I like `csv.DictReader` better in this case, because it consumes the header line for you and each "row" is a dictionary. Your specific text file sometimes seperates fields with repeated tabs to make it look prettier, so you'll have to take that into account in some way. In my snippet, I used a regular expression to replace all tab-clusters with a single tab.